# DataGrid view data manipulation: c#.net and datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a datagrid view which displays the following data. I am using c#.net Winforms.

```
 **Units**     **Area(in sqft)**     **Value(of Lin. Inch)**
   sqft          9                     144
   Lin.Inch      9                     144
   sqft          9                     144
```

In my above display the row wch corresponds to lin .inch should have the value 144 instead of 9.

My target grid view should be eliminating the last column.

```
    **Units**  **Area(in sqft)**    
   sqft          9                    
   Lin.Inch      144                  
   sqft          9                     
   sqft          9
```

can anyone help me how to achieve this?. Do you think whether to handle this at the sql side or in c#. Thanks in advance.

Hi All,
I found the answer myself.I added the below case statement in my sql to achive my results.

```
                 in my sql query :
                  (SELECT 
                   CASE 
                   WHEN unit = 'Sqft' THEN Area
                   WHEN unit = 'Lin.Inch' THEN Value(of Li.inch)
                   END) AS AREA
```

Comment: Can you show us how you add these to the datagridview ? Also you should try some debug messages to see why 9 is being displayed rather than 144.

Comment: Thanks for your response. actually units, area, value of are the exact column values from the database.

Comment: so there is no point in debugging .

Comment: Can you post the code you use then ?

Comment: Hi I found it myself. I used a Case statement in my query and it worked. I will post my answer. Thanks again .